# using a custom nstextfieldcell in an nstextfield

Tags: nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I have a custom nstextfieldcell.

I thought I could drag a textfield to a xib and click on it's cell, then change the cell's class to my custom class.That doesn't work.

Also, I thought I could drag the custom cell from the library (i made a plugin) over the textfield and it would set the new cell like in a table. That doesn't work either.

Does anybody know how to use a custom cell in a textfield?

One thing that I noticed, if I have the bwtoolkit plugin installed, I can see the plugin's custom cells in the list of available cells for the textfieldcell's class but I do not see mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to change the superclass in my classDescription file. It was set as NSView and it needed to supclass an NSTextFieldCell